# unknown directive "valid_referers"

Tags: nginx

Here's what I have in my configuration file:

```
location /media {
    alias /var/www/my-site.com/videotube/media;
    valid_referers none blocked my-site.com *.my-site.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

When I restart nginx it fails with message `unknown directive "valid_referers"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have mod_valid_referers  installed